# Error al enviar correo en Azure Application

Tags: azure

Tengo un api desarrollado con .NetCore que envía correos ante ciertos eventos. Vamos a cambiar la forma de enviar los correos para que se haga a traves del API Grahp de microsoft. Para ello, tengo la siguiente función:

```
private static void SendMailMessageService(IConfiguration configuration, string template, string toMail)
{
    Microsoft.Identity.Client.IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = 
        Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(configuration["AzureMail:ClientId"])
            .WithTenantId(configuration["AzureMail:TenantId"])
            .WithClientSecret(configuration["AzureMail:ClientSecret"])
            .Build();

    Microsoft.Graph.Auth.ClientCredentialProvider authProvider =
        new Microsoft.Graph.Auth.ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

    var client = new Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

    Microsoft.Graph.Message msg = new Microsoft.Graph.Message()
    {
        Subject = configuration["AzureMail:Subject"].ToString(),
        Body = new Microsoft.Graph.ItemBody()
        {
            Content = template,
            ContentType = Microsoft.Graph.BodyType.Html
        },
        ToRecipients = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Recipient>() {
            new Microsoft.Graph.Recipient {
                EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress {
                    Address = toMail
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var request = client.Me.SendMail(msg, false).Request();

    var result = request.PostAsync();
    result.Wait();
}
```

Cuando llamo a la función, esta lanzando una excepción con el código `NoPermissionsInAccessToken`.
En la aplicación de azure está asignado `Mail.Send`.

¿Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 0):

he hecho algunos cambios en el código. El nuevo es este que viene a continuación, donde se obtiene el token para un usuario/contraseña concreto.

```
private static void SendMailMessageService(IConfiguration configuration, string template, string user)
{
    Microsoft.Identity.Client.IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication =
        Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(configuration["AzureMail:ClientId"])
            .WithTenantId(configuration["AzureMail:TenantId"])
            .Build();

    var str = configuration["AzureMail:Key"];
    var pwd = new System.Security.SecureString();
    foreach (char c in str) pwd.AppendChar(c);

    string[] scopes = new string[] { "mail.send" };
    publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(
        scopes, configuration["AzureMail:UserFrom"], pwd
    ).ExecuteAsync().Wait();
    Microsoft.Graph.Auth.UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider =
        new Microsoft.Graph.Auth.UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

    Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient graphClient =
        new Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

    Microsoft.Graph.Message msg = new Microsoft.Graph.Message()
    {
        Subject = configuration["AzureMail:Subject"].ToString(),
        Body = new Microsoft.Graph.ItemBody()
        {
            Content = template,
            ContentType = Microsoft.Graph.BodyType.Html
        },
        ToRecipients = new List<Microsoft.Graph.Recipient>() {
            new Microsoft.Graph.Recipient {
                EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress {
                    Address = user
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var request = graphClient.Me.SendMail(msg, false).Request();

    var result = request.PostAsync();
    result.Wait();
}
```

He confirmado que la aplicación en Azure AD tiene asignado los permisos de envio de correos (delegados) para el usuario que tengo configurado en mi app.

Aun así, cuando lanzo esta función, me está devolviendo la siguiente excepción:

```
One or more errors occurred. (AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.
```

¿Os suena que puede estar pasando? Llevo días con esto y no consigo hacer el envío del correo.